# Failed to grant selinux permission for ioctl

Tags: ioctl, selinux

I got following selinux permission issues:

> [ 35.353551] type=1400 audit(38.680:14): avc: denied { ioctl } for
>   pid=266 comm="multilink" path="socket:[12798]" dev="sockfs" ino=12798
>   ioctlcmd=0x8946 scontext=u:r:multilink:s0 tcontext=u:r:multilink:s0
>   tclass=socket permissive=1
>
> [ 35.353789] type=1400 audit(38.680:16): avc: denied { ioctl } for
>   pid=266 comm="multilink" path="socket:[12799]" dev="sockfs" ino=12799
>   ioctlcmd=0x8933 scontext=u:r:multilink:s0 tcontext=u:r:multilink:s0
>   tclass=packet_socket permissive=1

I tried to add following rules to fix this issue:

> allowxperm multilink self:socket ioctl SIOCETHTOOL;
>
> allowxperm multilink self:packet_socket ioctl SIOCGIFINDEX;

But, it didn't work, same issues occurred again.

Do I miss something ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding another rule will fix this issue:

> allow multilink self:socket { create ioctl };
>
> allow multilink self:packet_socket { create ioctl };